# Google Webmaster Tools Errors 400 and 405

Tags: seo, google-search-console

What action does Google's crawler take for errors 400 and 405?

Looks like few months ago I had a bug, and a few pages available only for signed in users were indexed by Google. Right now all these page appear in **crawl errors** with errors 400 and 405. The bug is fixed, but Google keeps crawling them and updating the Detected column.

How do I stop Google crawling them? Should I send 404 or 410 instead?

What is the documented action for 400 and 405?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented action for those errors as far as I know but they are generally treated as any 4xx error. For your situation, perhaps a 401 Unauthorized would be more appropriate.

As for Google Webmaster Tools, it's notoriously slow at updating its crawl errors section. If a URL still returns a 4xx or 5xx code then it can takes months for Google to stop trying it, even with no links to it.